# Splash Screen via AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need that until xml parsing in background AsyncTask method is done a splash screen will be displayed so I created Loadingscreen activity with inner AsyncTask class and on the onPostExecute() I pass to mainactivity with intent but it wont work, splash screen is not displayed .

loadingactivity:

```
public class LoadingPage extends Activity
{    static ArrayList<WebPage> wps; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    //new getParseData().execute();

    try 
    {
        wps=new getParseData().execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

class getParseData extends AsyncTask<Void ,Void,ArrayList<WebPage>>
{
     ArrayList<WebPage>wps;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<WebPage> doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        WebPage ynet= new WebPage(R.drawable.ynet,    "http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml","http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss6.xml","http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss3.xml");
        WebPage walla=new WebPage(R.drawable.walla, "http://rss.walla.co.il/?w=/1/0/12/@rss.e","http://rss.walla.co.il/?w=/2/0/12/@rss.e","http://rss.walla.co.il/?w=/3/0/12/@rss.e");
        WebPage  nrg= new WebPage(R.drawable.maariv,   "http://rss.nrg.co.il/news/","http://rss.nrg.co.il/finance","http://rss.nrg.co.il/sport");

        ArrayList <WebPage>wps=new ArrayList<WebPage>();

        wps.add(ynet);
        wps.add(walla);
        wps.add(nrg);
        boolean coteretfilled=false;
        boolean linkfilled=false;
        boolean imgfilled=false;
        for(int y=0;y<wps.size();y++)
        {
            WebPage currentwp=wps.get(y);

            for(int i=0;i<currentwp.urls.length;i++)
            {
                ArrayList<TitlesVieLinks> tl=new ArrayList<TitlesVieLinks>();
                String urlString=currentwp.urls[i];
                try 
                {
                    URL url=new URL(urlString);
                    XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser parser=factory.newPullParser();
                    InputStream is=url.openStream();
                    parser.setInput(is,null);
                    boolean item=false;
                    boolean title=false;
                    boolean link=false;
                    boolean description=false;
                    String coteret="";
                    String _link = "";
                    //String _imglink ="";
                    String tagname="";
                    String result="";
                    int eventype=parser.getEventType();
                    while(eventype!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                    {  
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                        {  
                            tagname=parser.getName();
                            if(item)
                            {
                                if(tagname.equals("title"))
                                    title=true;
                                if(tagname.equals("link"))
                                    link=true;
                                if(tagname.equals("description"))
                                    description=true;
                            }
                            else//not item
                            {
                                if(tagname.equals("item"))
                                    item=true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                        {
                            tagname=parser.getName();
                            if(tagname.equals("item"))
                                item=false;
                        }
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                        {
                            if(title)
                            {
                                coteret=parser.getText();
                                coteretfilled=true;
                                title=false;
                            }
                            if(link)
                            {
                                _link=parser.getText();
                                linkfilled=true;
                                link=false;
                            }
                            if(description)
                            {
                                String cdata = parser.getText();
                                Log.i("Info", cdata);

                                int idxStart = cdata.indexOf("src=");
                                if (idxStart > 0)
                                {
                                    int idxEnd = Math.max(cdata.indexOf(".jpg"), cdata.indexOf(".png"));//returns the greater of 2 int values 
                                    if (idxEnd > 0)
                                    {
                                        result = cdata.substring(idxStart+5, idxEnd+4);                     
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    result="";
                                Log.i("InfoResult", result);

                                imgfilled=true;
                                description=false;
                            }
                            if(coteretfilled && linkfilled && imgfilled)
                            {
                                TitlesVieLinks titlink=new TitlesVieLinks(coteret, _link,result);   
                                tl.add(titlink);
                                coteretfilled=false;
                                linkfilled=false;
                                imgfilled=false;
                            }
                        }
                        eventype = parser.next();
                    }//end of while loop 
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        currentwp.NewsTitles.addAll(tl);
                    }
                    else if(i==1)
                    {
                        currentwp.EconomicsTitles.addAll(tl);
                    }
                    else if(i==2)
                    {
                        currentwp.SportssTitles.addAll(tl);
                    }
                    tl.clear();
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }// end of inner for loop
        }//end of first loop
        Log.i("every thing is cool", wps.get(0).NewsTitles.size()+"");
        return wps;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WebPage> result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent i=new Intent(LoadingPage.this,NewsMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
}
```

mainactivity:

```
 public class NewsMainActivity extends Activity 
 {
      static ArrayList<WebPage>wps;
      WebPage wp;
      NewsListAadpter adapter;
      public static final int YNET_WP_POS = 0;
      public static final int WALLA_WP_POS = 1;
      public static final int NRG_WP_POS = 2;

     ListView newsListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)           
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_main);
    wps= LoadingPage.wps;
    adapter=new NewsListAadpter(this);
    fillNews( R.drawable.ynet, YNET_WP_POS, adapter);
    fillNews( R.drawable.walla, WALLA_WP_POS, adapter);
    fillNews( R.drawable.maariv, NRG_WP_POS, adapter);

    newsListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
    newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

     private void fillNews(int drawableId, int position, NewsListAadpter adapter)//this func is used in the onpost     
{
      adapter.addImageSeperator(drawableId, position);
      adapter.addSeparatorItem("חדשות");
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        adapter.addItem(wps.get(position).getNewsTitles().get(i));      //3    first titles from news       
    }
        adapter.addLink(drawableId, position, 0, "עוד בחדשות");
        adapter.addSeparatorItem("ספורט");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        adapter.addItem(wps.get(position).getSportssTitles().get(i));               
    }
        adapter.addLink(drawableId, position,1, "עוד בספורט");
        adapter.addSeparatorItem("כלכלה");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        adapter.addItem(wps.get(position).getEconomicsTitles().get(i));             
    }
        adapter.addLink(drawableId, position, 2, "עוד בכלכלה");
}
```

manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           package="com.ravbm.newsreader"
           android:versionCode="1"
           android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="3"
     android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/news_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
         android:name="com.ravbm.newsreader.NewsMainActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name="com.ravbm.newsreader.AllNewsActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_all_news"
         android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.ravbm.newsreader.LoadingPage"
               >
         <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i tried instead of calling:

```
wps=new getParseData().execute().get();
```

the app works well but the loading page is not displayed instead there is a blankpage so i tried to call asynctask without the get:

```
new getParseData().execute();
```

and what happens is that the loading page is displayed but app crushes      immediately.
plz helpme find out whats not right.

Comment: if withiut `get()` method app is crashing then share crash logs

Comment: Why have you used get()? I think if you remove that, it should work fine.

Comment: I highly recommend you DON'T use AsyncTask because it WILL behave in ways that are awkward to the user when your application throws an ANR or crashes during the execution of doInBackground. I will try to write you up an answer with an IntentService and ResultReceiver, as this pattern doesn't break the lifecycle of your app as an AsyncTask would. It's totally worth the extra lines of code because it's way more robust :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so like I said in my comment, this will be an answer that doesn't actually answer your question but does answer your question by providing the same functionality you're looking for in a more stable way. This is because if your `LoadingPage` activity crashes or throws an ANR, your app will quit/exit, but then when your `AsyncTask` is done, it will STILL launch the `NewsMainActivity` even though your app has already quit... And that's bad mkay :)

One word of caution though; make sure that your `Webpage` class (the one you're returning to the `onPostExecute()` method) implements `Parcelable`. This is an easier and neater way than using a global static variable and just expecting that to always work. It's very possible to do it that way and not wrong, but it's not neat code.

These code samples will illustrate how you'll have to implement an `IntentService` and a `ResultReceiver` but you'll have to do a little work yourself too. Lets start by building our `IntentService`

```
public class LoadingService extends IntentService {
    public static final String RECEIVER_KEY = "receiver";
    public static final String SUCCESS_KEY = "success";
    public static final int SUCCESS_CODE = 0;
    public static final String ERROR_KEY = "error";
    public static final int ERROR_CODE = 1;

    public LoadingService() {
        super("LoadingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER_KEY);
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();

        if (receiver == NULL) return;

        try {
            /*
            So what you wanna do here is everything you currently do in doInBackground()
            It's very probably just as simple as copying it over and executing it here
            */

            /*
            These next two lines are only needed if your Webpage class implements Parcelable
            In that case we give it back to the LoadingPage Activity

            Now if you're not going the Parcelable route, replace the following two lines with
            code to put the Webpages into your global static variable
            */
            result.putParcelableArrayList(SUCCESS_KEY, /*NAME OF YOUR WEBPAGES LIST HERE*/);
            receiver.send(SUCCESS_CODE, result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result.putString(ERROR_KEY, "Something went wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            receiver.send(ERROR_CODE, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we'll have to register it in our `Manifest` too so simply add the following

`<service name=".LoadingService" />`

Now here's how to start it from your splash activity and receive results back, then start the `NewsMainActivity`

```
public class LoadingPage extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        //This starts the loading service and calls mReceiver when done
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingPage.this, LoadingService.class);
        intent.putExtra(LoadingService.RECEIVER_KEY, mReceiver);
        startService(intent);
    }

    final ResultReceiver mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        protected void onResultReceived(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == LoadingService.SUCCESS_CODE) {
                //THIS PART IS ONLY USEFUL WHEN WEBPAGE IMPLEMENTS PARCELABLE
                final ArrayList<Webpage> webpages = resultData.getParcelableArrayList(
                        LoadingService.SUCCESS_KEY);
                if (webpages != null && webpages.size > 0) {
                    //HERE YOU START YOUR MAIN ACTIVITY WITH THE WEBPAGES WE RECEIVED
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity.WEBPAGES_KEY, webpages);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                //NOW IF WEBPAGE DOESN'T IMPLEMENT PARCELABLE, ONLY START THE ACTIVITY
                //SO EITHER USE THE CODE ABOVE OR THE 1 LINE BELOW
                startActivity(new Intent(LoadingPage.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else if (resultCode == LoadingService.ERROR_CODE) {
                final String error = resultData.getString(LoadingService.ERROR_KEY);
                //DISPLAY AN ERROR MESSAGE HERE, LIKE: COULD NOT RETRIEVE DATA
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `LoadingPage` starts the Loading service, which does the background things you need it to do, then it sends a signal to the `ResultReceiver` when it's either done or hit an error. In the `ResultReceiver` we check if the result was a `SUCCESS` or an `ERROR`. If we had a success, it will start the following `Activity`

```
public class NewsMainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String WEBPAGES_KEY = "webpages";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_main);

        final ArrayList<Webpage> webpages = getIntent()
                .getParcelableArrayList(WEBPAGES_KEY);
        //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE :)
    }
}
```

And that should be it! If you have any questions, I'd love to hear 'em :)

Comment: thijs Koppen ,thank u very much for your answer i will try to implement your code but still i feel i dont quit understand the asynctask behaviour if i pass to next activity in the onpostExecute which makes sure that doinbackground finished retrieving the data so why should be any problem?

Comment: I'll try to explain it better to the best of my knowledge. Imagine you have two bowls, in one you have your app and nothing in the other. Now when you start a new activity, you put this activity in bowl number 1, where your app already was. Starting an AsyncTask puts this task in the second bowl, and when it finishes, it moves back over to bowl 1. Now when you start an AsyncTask (bowl 2) and empty bowl 1 (your app quits, crashes or is force stopped), moving back to bowl 1 should be impossible, but AsyncTask doesn't care and recreates the first bowl, breaking your application's life cycle :(

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the log it will easy to find the main reason for the crash.
Check with replacing `finish()` with `LoadingPage.this.finish()`